cs1robots python module: Robot won't turn
So i have been trying to solve the rain2.wld file in the cs1robots module. here is the code that i have so far:
from cs1robots import *

load_world("rain2")
h = Robot(avenue=3, street=6, orientation='S', beepers=10)
h.set_trace("blue")
h.set_pause(0.3)

h.drop_beeper()
h.move()

while not h.on_beeper():
    if h.right_is_clear():
        h.drop_beeper()
        h.move()
    elif h.front_is_clear():
        h.move()
    elif h.left_is_clear():
        h.turn_left()


output of the code
so basically i wanted it to check for every "window" and place a beeper there. but this is not doing it.
any help would be very appreciated
This is the output that i am going for is: planned output

"but this is not doing it".  What exactly is it doing?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@ewokx i modified my question by adding the output that i am trying to achieve. hopefully that helps. thanks
